# How to prove $ P (A^c ∩ B^c) = 1 − P(A) − P(B) + P(A ∩ B)$?

Tags: probability

$$  P (A^c ∩ B^c) = 1 − P(A) − P(B) + P(A ∩ B).$$

Can someone help me to proof this.

I know that  $P(A^c)=1- P(A)$ but am now sure how exactly how to use it

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: De Morgan's Law

Comment: P (A ∩ B)=P(A)P(B) and also P(A ∪ B)= P(A)+P(B) -P(A∩B) but i don't have any idea what to do then..

Comment: That is only in the case that A and B are independent events. First use De Morgan's Law on $A^c \cap B^c$ and from that you can use the fact (that it should not be difficult for you to prove, if you have not done so) $P(D^c)=1-P(D)$. Now, you will have $D=A\cup B$. I think you can work out the rest by yourself.

Comment: @p.mc You can only say $P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B)$ if $A$ and $B$ are independent, but they aren't necessarily independent here, so you can't use that property.

Answer (score 2):

First, you should prove for any sets $A$ and $B$ that $(A \cup B)^{c} = A^{c} \cap B^{c}$.  This is one of DeMorgan's laws.  It's easy to prove, so try it.  If you have trouble, let me know.

Then notice that $P(A^{c} \cap B^{c}) = P( (A\cup B)^{c})$.  As you said, for a set $G$, $P(G^{c}) = 1 - P(G)$, so that:

$P( (A\cup B)^{c}) = 1 - P(A \cup B)$.

Finally, there is this nice formula that $P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)$ (which you mentioned in a comment).  So we get:

$1 - P(A \cup B) = 1 - P(A) - P(B) + P(A \cap B)$, which is what we wanted.

Comment: Thank you  .That was really helpful. I get it now

Answer (score 0):

Applying 
$$
P(D^c)=1-P(D)
$$
for $$D=A\cup B,$$ and use a formula for $P(A\cup B)$ what do you get?